# Re-render current form in submit-hook under certain conditions

Tags: 7, forms

I have a form:

```
function _scratch_tests_for_users() {
  $current_user_number = current_user_number_from_session();
  $form = drupal_get_form("_scratch_forms_test_for_user", $current_user_number);
  return drupal_render($form);
}
```

With the form callback:

```
function _scratch_forms_test_for_user($form, &$form_values, $current_user_number) {
  $form["user"] = array(
    "#type" => "value",
    "#value" => $current_user_number,
  );
  $form["submit"] = array(
    "#type" => "markup",
    "#markup" => "Play number {$current_user_number}",
  );
  return $form;
}
```

And a submit callback:

```
function _scratch_forms_test_for_user_submit($form, &$form_values) {
  if ($form_values["values"]["user"]) > 3) {
    _store_some_stuff();
    return "ready";
  }
  else {
    //...re-render the form.
  }
}
```

In above example code, I would want to render that form three times, the fourth time, values should be stored.

Note that my actual code is a lot more complex and has more complex criteria then simply "the first three times"; just to avoid answers like "just copy-paste the form three times" :).

Comment: I think you should tell us what you really want to achieve. Is this some kind of multi step form?

Comment: Yes. Sort of. It is part of a game-system. Where this particular form should be ran for each user in a list, and once all users have filled it out, iterate to the next step (in a statemachine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that forcing rerendering on that level is not possible. 
Logic for rendering, or re-rendering needs to be at the level where the "`drupal_get_form`" is called.

Answer (score 1):

[drupal_rebuild_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_rebuild_form/7)() constructs a new $form from the information in $form_state.

I think you can also set [$form_state['rebuild']](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/example-for-form-staterebuild) = TRUE; in a validation or submit hook as well to trigger the form rebuild.